# CMAKE error: TBB variable set to not found

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, tbb

System: Linux

I am getting the following error when trying to run a C++ code. When I run cmake .., I get -

```
srishti@ubuntu:~/realtimeKCF/build$ cmake ..
FINALLL TBB_LIBRARIES = 'optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so;debug;TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND'
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG (ADVANCED)
linked by target "DSKCFcpp" in directory /home/srishti/realtimeKCF

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/srishti/realtimeKCF/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I also searched for:

> TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG (ADVANCED)

but I can't find this anywhere. Can someone please help me with this? I am just having this error stopping me from running the code.

Comment: Did you search for just `TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG`?

Comment: @John  Yes, I typed `locate -i TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG` . It didn't give me any result.

Comment: Try a recursive grep in the source directory.

Comment: @John  Hi, I did. I am attaching the snapshot of the result: [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/n13vwh.png[/IMG]

Comment: The variable is set by `FindTBB.cmake` script, shipped with the project. Most likely, the name of the variable is never used directly in the script. Instead, the script concatenates the variable's name from other variables. The variable is intended to contain path to debug version of `tbb` library. So, you need to provide this library for make things work. Alternatively, you may set this variable in CMake cache to the release version of the library, which is already found (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev It worked. Thanks.